# How accurate are Google's pronunciations of Welsh words?

Tags: pronunciation, welsh

I'm a complete beginner in Welsh and it would be very convenient to use Google Translate to show me how to pronounce words and phrases. Can a native speaker or advanced learner tell me if using Google would give me anything like a halfway decent accent?

Comment: My versions of Google translate have no sound output whatsoever, so if you're getting synthesized Welsh, you may have to specify how / what version.

Comment: Gweiadur has audio pronunciation for Welsh https://www.gweiadur.com/en (registration gives you more options), you need to click on the Welsh words if you want to use the English-Welsh dictionary to hear it

Comment: @user6726 -- it's a bit weird, it only works for me if I put the Welsh word or phrase into the LH column (the L1, which is a bit counter-intuitive).

Comment: So you put the Welsh spelling into the ?English column and play that? That is totally not what Welsh sounds like.

Comment: OK, thanks. That easy route out is barred then :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate doesn't do that, and I'm not optimistic that it ever will. However, there *is* a [synthesizing website for Welsh](http://techiaith.cymru/speech/text-to-speech/?lang=en), where you can feed in text and it plays it back to you. I have no opinion of the phonetic accuracy of the system, but you could compare [these recordings](https://www.jlb2011.co.uk/wales/sounds/index.htm) which is non-synthesized. The latter website notes:

> The Welsh language is spoken with a different accent in different
> parts of Wales. In particular, Welsh spoken in North Wales sounds very
> different from that spoken in South Wales, and that in Mid Wales is
> different again! As most of my time has been spent in South Wales, my
> pronunciation of places in South Wales will be more authentic than for
> elsewhere

which explains why the first synthesizer diverges from the recordings.